# outproc COM Server in DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I have a COM object in my DLL which I would like to expose out-of-proc. I know that out-of-proc COM object can only be used from within an executable. What I'm wondering if it's possible to use something like dllhost.exe or runddl32.exe to host my DLL and expose my object as out-of-proc? I read something about surrogates, could anyone off some info on how I could do this?

My end goal is to have an out-of-proc COM object, hosted in a DLL (which is hosted in an executable using LoadLibrary, etc). This COM object would utilize the Singleton Class Factory available in ATL. It will be a class that shares data to all processes that connect to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - [use surrogate activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Option 2 - use COM+ Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Component Services - create a "server" COM+ application and just add your classes there.

Anyway you'll need marshalling stuff for the interfaces implemented by your object - either a proxy/stub pair or (if all interafces are Automation-compatible) a typelib.